# How to move dropdown arrow left side instead of right side which is by default in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

From the below code, I can customize only dropdown icon but I can't move to the left side. like this picture.
[image]

```
Widget testDropdown(){
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        items: <String>[
          'Item 1',
          'Item 2',
          'Item 3',
          'Item 4',
          'Item 5'
        ].map((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onChanged: (value) {
          print(value);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm afraid you should make your own dropdown, there is nothing you could tweak with [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ec9813a5005f4c3e75a5a9f42ce53ae280959085/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L1317-L1346).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrap it with [Directionality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) widget with textDirection: `TextDirection.rtl` property

```
  Widget testDropdown() {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          items: <String>['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'].map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            print(value);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused whether It has side effect or not, but It actually works. Thanks for teaching a new technique!

Comment: @Tokenyet there's no any side effect and it's working perfect.

Comment: I think this could mess up text layout within the widget, if you have a mix of RTL and LTR text in the same dropdown label.